# In Python, is it a bad idea for a directory module's __init__.py to do this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I have a package with several subdirectories containing `__init__.py` files. These files perform checks and initialization jobs.

Now I also have in some of these folders a file that isn't supposed to be referenced directly by an `import` as it relies on the sanity checks performed in its respective `__init__.py`. Let's call these "hidden modules" - as a convention I use an underscore to make those obvious.

Is it a bad idea to do the following inside my `__init__.py` (with a `_implementation.py` located in the same folder):

```
import os, sys
if sanity_check_successful:
    from ._implementation import *
    __all__ = sys.modules[__name__ + "._implementation"].__all__
```

The idea should be clear, I am trying to provide meaningful error information at each respective module level in the package whenever a sanity check fails.

Is this a bad idea, i.e. copying the `__all__` array over from the "hidden module"? If so, why and are there better alternatives?

Bonus points: is there a more concise way of writing those two lines?:

```
    from ._implementation import *
    __all__ = sys.modules[__name__ + "._implementation"].__all__
```

In particular it itches me that I have to use a string `"._implementation"` in one place and as a module name in another.

Comment: Why do you need to test for `__main__` at all? What are the consequences if people try to do that? Anything short of bodily harm does not warrant you worrying about such erroneous usage.

Comment: And if you want to set `__all__` from the `._implementation` module, that's fine, but just import it directly: `from ._implementation import __all__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are simpler ways to set `__all__` from the `._implementation` submodule; setting `__all__` otherwise fine:

```
from ._implementation import *
from ._implementation import __all__
```

This simply imports `__all__` and binds it to the local module namespace `__all__`.

Comment: Aha! Now I get you :) ... was just asking in a comment how this would solve the problem. So basically I am importing everything from `_implementation` and *then* overwriting the local `__all__` with the one taken from `_implementation`, right?

Comment: Given the latest edit to the question, I think this is the clearest and most idiomatic way to do what the OP wants, and it's a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler than Martijn Pieters' answer:

If you include `'__all__'` in the `__all__` list of `._implementation`, it will be automatically imported by your single `from ._implementation import *` line.

---

As to your main question, whether this is a bad idea…

Well, it depends on what you're doing. This basically makes your package look exactly like its `_implementation` module. If that's all you're doing, that's fine… but in that case, why not just move `_implementation` into `__init__` in the first place?

If you're trying to merge multiple modules into one, you probably want to *add* all of their `__all__` lists into a single one. The stdlib has examples of this, like `collections`, and the usual pattern is:

```
from collections.abc import *
import collections.abc
__all__ += collections.abc.__all__
```

That may seem a little verbose, but it's certainly clear.

---

From your edited question, I think what you're doing is reasonable in exactly the same way that `collections` is, and the clearest and most idiomatic solution is to do the equivalent, but with `=` instead of `+=` (since you're just copying one list instead of adding multiple lists together).

But, since this:

```
import foo
bar = foo.bar
```

… is pretty much equivalent (as in close enough for your use case) to:

```
from foo import bar
```

… Martijn Pieters' answer is an obvious simplication:

```
from ._implementation import *
from ._implementation import __all__
```

So, I'd do that.

Comment: But that would mean that `from packagename import *` suddenly `__all__` would be imported too, mucking up the importing namespace. This is not that great an idea!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: so that would violate the Zen of Python or be un-pythonic in some other way?

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Importing `__all__` should be done explicitly; there are drawbacks to using `from somewhere import *` that `__all__` is supposed to help guard against, including `__all__` in that list would defeat that again as you normally do *not* want to import `__all__` into your module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: True. But modules that `from package import *` can just do so before defining `__all__`. And if this is only meant to be used by top-level code, the `__all__` doesn't matter anyway. So, it really depends on the use case, and I'm not sure exactly what the OP's use case is.

Comment: @abarnert: Defining `__all__` in the package `__init__` implies you can do `from package import *`, without then finding that you got more than just the API methods that were supposed to be exported. `__all__` is a surprising name to find in your own namespace when you don't expect it and weren't planning to set one yourself.

Comment: @abarnert: edited the question to make more obvious what is going on, my previous edit to the answer "hid" that. This is in fact one of the branches of an `if`. I don't want to have this stuff even visible to Python unless the sanity check succeeds (version compatibility and such).

Comment: @abarnert: and no, this is at each respective level and therefore I don't want to join them, but I'm aware I could do that :)